# find common words in multiple paragraphs Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

hello I have 40 paragraphs. each paragraph contains about 250 words. I want to find common words for paragraph and save results in comma separated file. I will show example.

```js
var para1 = "this is para one. I am cat. I am 10 years old. I like fish";
var para2 = "this is para two. I am dog. my age is 12. I can swim";
var para3 = "this is para three. I am cat. I am 9 years. I like rat";
var para4 = "this is para four. I am rat. my age is secret. I hate cat";
var para5 = "this is para five. I am dog. I am 10 years old. I like fish";
```

I need results as

this , 5

is , 5

para , 5

I , 13

am , 8

cat ,3

.....

like this. I also want to exclude some words, like I , am , which are not necessary. However I think I can do excluding part if I found a method to save results as above.

Comment: Just split the strings using whitespace, and then store them in a dictionary. Then you can keep track of the count of each word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply iterate through all your paragraphs, and then split them up by whitespace character. If you want to exclude punctuation marks, then it might make sense to perform a basic regex replace before splitting.

You can then collect all of these in a dictionary, so you can tally the total number of counts per unique word found in all the paragraphs. For that reason, it is often a good idea to convert the entire string to lowercase first, so that you don't have seemingly duplicate words that are counted separately, e.g. `Hello` and `hello`.

To add a exclusion list, you can check if individual words matches the list before adding them to the dictionary.

```js
var para1 = "this is para one. I am cat. I am 10 years old. I like fish";
var para2 = "this is para two. I am dog. my age is 12. I can swim";
var para3 = "this is para three. I am cat. I am 9 years. I like rat";
var para4 = "this is para four. I am rat. my age is secret. I hate cat";
var para5 = "this is para five. I am dog. I am 10 years old. I like fish";

const dict = {};
const wordsToExclude = ['this', 'i', 'am'];
const paras = [para1, para2, para3, para4, para5];
paras.forEach(p => {
  const words = p.toLowerCase().replace(/[\.,]/g, '').split(' ');
  words.forEach(w => {
    // GUARD: Exclude certain words
    if (wordsToExclude.includes(w)) {
      return;
    }
    
    // OPTIONAL GUARD: Exclude numbers
    if (w.match(/^\d+$/)) {
      return;
    }
    
    dict[w] = (dict[w] ? dict[w] : 0) + 1;
  });
});

console.log(dict);
```

Pro-tip: If you are supporting very modern browsers or are using TypeScript, you can change the line `dict[w] = (dict[w] ? dict[w] : 0) + 1;` to use the null coalescence operator: `dict[w] = (dict[w] ?? 0) + 1;`

Comment: omg, this is perfect, actually I did not know about dict function in javascript. This solved my problem. Thanks a lot